# AWS Chalice - CI/CD - Deploy under the same gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, continuous-deployment, chalice

When we use

```
chalice deploy
```

for a component which is to be available as REST endpoint, Chalice creates the Lambda and API on AWS infrastructure.

Every chalice project creates a new API with a unique id.
I want to be able deploy multiple chalice projects under the same API id. We want to be able to configure this API name/id and use it in CI/CD pipeline as well.

How do we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the new API ids is because chalice when using the `chalice deploy` command, it creates a file in `.chalice/deployed` for that stage. In that file it would have the ID it would re-deploy to.

There are two solutions if you are using a CI/CD pipeline.

First being you can issue the FIRST deploy to create the file on your project LOCALLY. From your local machine you can run `chalice deploy --stage {YourStageHere}` and it will create the proper file and you can push that into your repo to save it. Then the pipeline will read from that file for the API ID.

The second being is much more in depth. It would require setting up a changeset to the pipeline. There is a very good starting tutorial in the official documentation:

https://chalice-workshop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/todo-app/part2/02-pipeline.html